# Cannot read property of nodeName undefined on jQuery validation with select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

I am trying to add jQuery validation on my select2 drop-down. However, it keeps causing the javascript exception of "nodeName undefined", I am not sure what went wrong.

```
 $(".field-validation-required").each(function() {

     // output SELECT, if current html class is a select2 dropdown.
     console.log(this.nodeName); 

     $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
          required: "This field is required"
        }
     }); 
 });
```

My select2 dropdown contains the class '.field-validation-required' and I am trying to apply some jQuery validation on it. But it seems $(this) always causes that "Cannot read property of nodeName undefined" error.

Comment: Show us the relevant HTML markup; otherwise, I cannot duplicate your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My select2 dropdown contains the class `.field-validation-required` and I am trying to apply some jQuery validation on it. But it seems `$(this)` always causes that `"Cannot read property of nodeName undefined"` error.

Show us the relevant HTML markup; otherwise, I cannot duplicate your error.

---

Does your original `select` contain a unique `name`?  This is mandated by the plugin and a missing or duplicate `name` may be the root cause of your error message.

---

Is your `.field-validation-required` class on the original `select` element or on your dynamically created Select2 elements?

If it's on the `select` element, then it should work.  If it's on the Select2 element, then it will not work.

You can only apply jQuery Validate to `select`, `textarea`, certain `input`, and `contenteditable` elements... nothing else.

Target the original hidden `select` element instead of the Select2 element.  Then since the plugin will ignore all hidden elements, you'll need to set the `ignore` option to some jQuery selector that does not ignore your hidden `select` element.  For example, `ignore: []` will tell the plugin to ignore nothing and validate all hidden elements.

---

Alternatively, you can apply the `required` rule to your original `select` element by class or HTML5 attribute.  You'll still need to set the `ignore` option as described above.

```
<select name="myselect" class="required" ....
```

or

```
<select name="myselect" required="required" ....
```

Comment: Yeah, I finally found the root cause of this exception is because I have a div that contains the ".field-validation-required" class and the code was trying to validate that, which caused the exception.